# extract number in string "IDnumber bla bla:" with php

Tags: php, explode

how can i extract number in string with php, eg:

```
string = "bla1 bla2 ID1234 bla3 bla4:"
```

desireable output = 1234

I used `explode("ID",$string)`
but wrong output (=ID1234 bla3 bla4:)

Please help
Thank you

Comment: explode function only breaks a string into an array. If you want to extract the number you should do it manually.

Comment: How numbers are formatted in strings, always as ID1234 with prefix ID?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you search a single ID and if the number is at most 10 chars you can do it with strpos and substr :

```php
<?php
$string = "bla1 bla2 ID1234 bla3 bla4:";
$pos = strpos($string, 'ID');
if ($pos !== false)
    $n = (int) substr($string, 2 + $pos, 10); // found the ID
else
    $n = null ; // not found the ID
var_dump($n); // int(1234)
```